# How to stylize the jquery countdown

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-countdown

I am using the [jQuery countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) 
the source contains only the javascript needed to make the countdown works.
I am wondering how I can get the same "animated" style as the "black countdown" here http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Answer (score 1):

The source of Main.css styles it as follows:

```css
/**
 * Main module
 */
main a,
main a:link,
main a:visited {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
main a:hover,
main a:active,
main a:visited:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
main article {
  padding: 1em;
}
main [class*="pure-u-"]:first-child article {
  padding-left: 0;
}
main [class*="pure-u-"]:last-child article {
  padding-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
  main article {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}
.main-example {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 355px;
}
.main-example .countdown-container {
  height: 130px;
}
.main-example .time {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 95px;
  width: 65px;

  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  -moz-perspective: 500px;
  -ms-perspective: 500px;
  -o-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.main-example .count {
  background: #202020;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2.4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);

  -webkit-transform-style: flat;
  -moz-transform-style: flat;
  -ms-transform-style: flat;
  -o-transform-style: flat;
  transform-style: flat;
}
.main-example .count.top {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 50%;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.main-example .count.bottom {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent);
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.main-example .count.next {
}
.main-example .label {
  font-size: normal;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Animation start */
.main-example .count.curr.top {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
.main-example .count.next.bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
/* Animation end */
.main-example .flip .count.curr.top {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;

  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
.main-example .flip .count.next.bottom {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;

  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
  .main-example {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-example .countdown-container {
    height: 100px;
  }
  .main-example .time {
      height: 70px;
      width: 48px;
  }
  .main-example .count {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .main-example .label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    top: 72px;
  }
}
```